# Binding Property not found on ViewModel even though it exists

Tags: .net, maui, compiled-bindings

I created a model class called `Project` and also created a ViewModel class called `MainPageViewModel`.

What I want to implement is a simple table that has multiple columns. There should be one column named "Action" and that column should have one button.

Here is the XAML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="SharpTool.UI.MainPage"
             xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:SharpTool.UI.ViewModels"
             xmlns:models ="clr-namespace:SharpTool.UI.Models"
             x:DataType="viewmodel:MainPageViewModel">
    
    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout
            Padding="10, 10">
            <Border MinimumHeightRequest="50" StrokeThickness ="0.5">
    
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    
                    <Border StrokeThickness="0.1" Grid.Column="0">
                        <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" FontFamily="icon" FontSize="15" Text="Id" TextColor="Blue"/>
                    </Border>
    
                    <Border StrokeThickness="0.1" Grid.Column="1">
                        <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" FontFamily="icon" FontSize="15" Text="Name" TextColor="Blue"/>
                    </Border>
    
                    <Border StrokeThickness="0.1"  Grid.Column="2">
                        <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" FontFamily="icon" FontSize="15" Text="Discription" TextColor="Blue"/>
                    </Border>
    
                    <Border StrokeThickness="0.1" Grid.Column="3">
                        <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" FontFamily="icon" FontSize="15" Text="Version" TextColor="Blue"/>
                    </Border>
                        
                    <Border StrokeThickness="0.1" Grid.Column="4">
                        <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" FontFamily="icon" FontSize="15" Text="Action" TextColor="Blue"/>
                    </Border>
    
                </Grid>
    
            </Border>
    
            <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Projects}" >
    
                <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                    <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical"/>
                </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
    
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Project">
    
                        <Border MinimumHeightRequest="50" StrokeThickness ="0.5" >
    
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    
                                <Border StrokeThickness="0.1" Grid.Column="0">
                                    <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" FontFamily="icon" FontSize="15" Text="{Binding Id}" TextColor="Blue"/>
                                </Border>
    
                                <Border StrokeThickness="0.1" Grid.Column="1">
                                    <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" FontFamily="icon" FontSize="15" Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor="Blue"/>
                                </Border>
    
                                <Border StrokeThickness="0.1"  Grid.Column="2">
                                    <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" FontFamily="icon" FontSize="15" Text="{Binding Description}"  TextColor="Blue"/>
                                </Border>
    
                                <Border StrokeThickness="0.1" Grid.Column="3">
                                    <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" FontFamily="icon" FontSize="15" Text="{Binding Version}" TextColor="Blue"/>
                                </Border>
    
                                <Border StrokeThickness="0.1" Grid.Column="4">
    
                                    <Button
                                        Text="Click me"
                                        SemanticProperties.Hint="Counts the number of times you click"
                                        Command="{Binding GetProjectByCommand}"
                                        CommandParameter="2"
                                        HorizontalOptions="Center" />
                                </Border>
    
                            </Grid>
    
                        </Border>
    
                    </DataTemplate>
    
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
    
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    
</ContentPage>
```

I managed to implement the UI code but I have a problem. When I set the `x:DataType="models:Project"` in the `DataTemplate` I can't bind the ViewModel methods to buttons or
any other components.

It gives me an error:

> Binding: Property "GetProjectByCommand" not found on "SharpTool.UI.Models.Project".

If I remove this part:
`Command="{Binding GetProjectByCommand}"` in the button inside the `Grid`,
then the project builds and runs without any issues.

This is the ViewModel code:

```cs
[INotifyPropertyChanged]
public partial class MainPageViewModel
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    ObservableCollection<Project> projects = new();
    
    [ObservableProperty]
    public bool isBusy = false;
    
    public ICommand GetProjectByCommand { private set; get; }
    
    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        projects.Add(new Project { Id = 1, Name = "Project 1 Name", Description = "Project 1 Description", Version = "1.0" });
        projects.Add(new Project { Id = 2, Name = "Project 2 Name", Description = "Project 2 Description", Version = "1.0" });
        projects.Add(new Project { Id = 3, Name = "Project 3 Name", Description = "Project 3 Description", Version = "1.0" });
        projects.Add(new Project { Id = 4, Name = "Project 1 Name", Description = "Project 1 Description", Version = "1.0" });
        projects.Add(new Project { Id = 5, Name = "Project 2 Name", Description = "Project 2 Description", Version = "1.0" });
        projects.Add(new Project { Id = 6, Name = "Project 3 Name", Description = "Project 3 Description", Version = "1.0" });
        projects.Add(new Project { Id = 7, Name = "Project 1 Name", Description = "Project 1 Description", Version = "1.0" });
        projects.Add(new Project { Id = 8, Name = "Project 2 Name", Description = "Project 2 Description", Version = "1.0" });
        projects.Add(new Project { Id = 9, Name = "Project 3 Name", Description = "Project 3 Description", Version = "1.0" });
        projects.Add(new Project { Id = 10, Name = "Project 3 Name", Description = "Project 3 Description", Version = "1.0" });
    
        GetProjectByCommand = new Command<string>(GetProjectById);
    }
    
    private void GetProjectById(string id)
    {
        //query project list
    }
}
```

So, how do I bind that `GetProjectById` method to that button inside the Grid?

Comment: Property A has field _a, not a. Follow the naming conventions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is something that happens a lot. The issue here is that whenever you are in a control that shows items, the data-binding scope will change.

For you full page the view model is your `MainPageViewModel`. You then have a `CollectionView` that reads from the `Projects` property of your `MainPageViewModel`. So far, so good.

However, inside of your `CollectionView`, especially inside of your `ItemTemplate` you are no longer scoped to the rest of your page, but the binding context is now the type of whatever item you put in there, in your case `Project`. You can also see this because you have to specify `<DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Project">` which should indicate to you that you're now looking at `Project` objects and not the `MainPageViewModel` anymore.

There is multiple options to solve this. The most obvious, but not necessarily best, is to add the `GetProjectByCommand` to your `Project` object. However, technically this is probably a responsibility of your `MainPageViewModel`.

The other option is to change your binding to make sure that it looks at your `MainPageViewModel` again. In order to do this, change this line:

```xml
<Button
    Text="Click me"
    SemanticProperties.Hint="Counts the number of times you click"
    Command="{Binding GetProjectByCommand}"
    CommandParameter="2"
    HorizontalOptions="Center" />
```

to this:

```xml
<Button
    Text="Click me"
    SemanticProperties.Hint="Counts the number of times you click"
    Command="{Binding GetProjectByCommand, Source={x:Reference mainPage.BindingContext}}"
    CommandParameter="2"
    HorizontalOptions="Center" />
```

In order for this to work make sure that you add the `x:Name="mainPage"` attribute to your `ContentPage` node.

What this does is set the source of the binding to the `mainPage.BindingContext` which is your `MainPageViewModel`.

More information about this can also be found in my video about it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Or_qn8i8jVM

I just noticed that in my video I use a different syntax:

```xml
<Button
    Text="Click me"
    SemanticProperties.Hint="Counts the number of times you click"
    Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.GetProjectByCommand, Source={Reference mainPage}}"
    CommandParameter="2"
    HorizontalOptions="Center" />
```

Which is essentially the same but written different.